# How to batch export CloudWatch Logs to S3 using Lambda(python)

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

Based on AWS developer guide, [Here](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2015/12/announcing-amazon-cloudwatch-logs-batch-export-to-s3/), It does not tell you how to batch export CloudWatch Logs to S3 using Lambda. Below is my code using boto3, I've researched quite sometime now and could not find any that allow you to batch export CloudWatch Logs to S3 using Lambda.

Any Help is Appreciated!

```
import boto3
import collections
import time; time.time()

region = 'us-east-2'

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    client = boto3.client('logs')
    response = client.create_export_task(
    taskName='export to S3',
    logGroupName=('/aws/lambda/my_bucket'),
    logStreamNamePrefix='default',
    fromTime=456858943000,
    to=5655086899000,
    destination='my_bucket',
    destinationPrefix='default'
    )
    print(response)
```

Comment: What error messages/logging does it give you?

Comment: Bill, Thank you. It did not give me any error, the code above actually works, but only for one log group. I'd like to know if there's any way to batch export it by adding couple more lines of codes, I personally tried it myself but could not get it going.